# notepad++ user defined language for pseudocode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++, pseudocode

I have made a basic UDL in Notepad++ to comply with my way of writing pseudocode. However, one feature I need is for when I would write:

```
BEGIN Main
    ExampleSub
END

BEGIN SUBPROGRAM ExampleSub
    Display something...
END SUBPROGRAM ExampleSub
```

What I want is for Notepad++ to highlight the ExampleSub so that I know that it is a subprogram (kind of like how it highlights variables declared in PHP)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBPROGRAM as the start of a delimiter and ((EOL)) as the end of the delimiter to highlight the SUBPROGRAM statement and everything after it. UDLs are not as powerful as built-in languages, so nested ExampleSub references are not counted.

#### References

- [Limitations of User Defined Languages](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Limitations_Of_User_Defined_Languages)
- [User Defined Language Preferences](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages)
- [User Defined Language Configuration](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files)